# MIPS, using a constant as the base address of instruction sw

Tags: memory, mips

In MIPS, what would the following block of codes do???

```
addiu $t0, $0, 5
sw    $t1, 0($t0) # assume that $t1 is some constant
```

Since $t0 register is not a memory address(or is it? 0x00000005), I wonder where $t1 get stored to...

Answer (score 1):

This code would store `$t1` at the address `0x5`.

Or at least that's the intention. If you tried to run it, however, you'd find that the application would crash because the address `0x5` is not word-aligned.